# Looping through multiple divs and pulling each input value from each

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an html page the will dynamically add or remove inputs, all within a parent div, each having their own div to determine each seperatly.  I have the logic to loop through and find these child divs, however I cannot seem to figure out how to grab the inputs from each div, only the first child div even though I am looping through all children.

Any idea how?

html:

```
<div id="volumeRateDiv">
<div id="volumeRateDivNew_0" class="volumeRateDivChild">
    <input id="kc_start" type="number" name="kc_start" maxlength="9" step="1" min="0" placeholder="0">
    <input id="volume_rate" type="number" name="volume_rate" maxlength="12" step=".0001" min="0" placeholder="0.0000">
    <input id="delete_VolumeRate" type="button" name="delete_VolumeRate" value="Delete" onclick="removeItem('volumeRateDivNew_0')">
</div>
<div id="volumeRateDivNew_1" class="volumeRateDivChild">
    <input id="kc_start" type="number" name="kc_start" maxlength="9" step="1" min="0" placeholder="0">
    <input id="volume_rate" type="number" name="volume_rate" maxlength="12" step=".0001" min="0" placeholder="0.0000">
    <input id="delete_VolumeRate" type="button" name="delete_VolumeRate" value="Delete" onclick="removeItem('volumeRateDivNew_1')">
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("volumeRateDivChild");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    var div = divs[i];
    alert (div.className+" - "+div.id+" - "+document.getElementById("kc_start").value );
}
```

Comment: ID's **must** be unique...

Answer (score 0):

You could add the same index number (0, 1, etc) to the end of the inputs' IDs, and then use that in the for loop, eg:

```
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    var div = divs[i];
    alert (div.className+" - "+div.id+" - "+document.getElementById("kc_start_" + i).value );
}
```

Comment: The issue I have here is, I am using style sheets based on that name, unless there is a way to wildcard the style sheet for kc_start* or something, I have never done.

Comment: there is no element with id like `kc_start_`

Comment: @DennisHepworth Just to be clear, are you unable to change the style sheet, or the html?

Comment: div[id^="kc_start"] will give you a css declaration for div's with id's that start with kc_start

Comment: I can change both, just learning Style sheets so wasn't familiar with wild-carding type thing.  I will investigate further into the above suggestion, and do understand should be unique, but I was thinking of it like xml, where you have a parent, and you could use the same child name on different parents.

Comment: Although not required, I find it best practice to use classes for CSS, as it keeps specificity problems to a minimum. So ideally I would try to set the HTML like so: `<input id="kc_start_0" class="kc_start">`. Then you can target it in CSS via `.kc_start {}` and use my solution above to target it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment in your answer is correct all id's should be unique.

If you can be certain that the input you want to extract the value of is always the first child then you could do the same as this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/williamtdavies/4awtj869/)

```
<div id="volumeRateDiv">
<div id="volumeRateDivNew_0" class="volumeRateDivChild">
    <input id="kc_start" type="number" name="kc_start" maxlength="9" step="1" min="0" placeholder="0" value="0"/>
        <input id="volume_rate" type="number" name="volume_rate" maxlength="12" step=".0001" min="0" placeholder="0.0000"/>
        <input id="delete_VolumeRate" type="button" name="delete_VolumeRate" value="Delete" onclick="removeItem('volumeRateDivNew_0')"/>
</div>
<div id="volumeRateDivNew_1" class="volumeRateDivChild">
    <input id="kc_start" type="number" name="kc_start" maxlength="9" step="1" min="0" placeholder="0" value="0"/>
    <input id="volume_rate" type="number" name="volume_rate" maxlength="12" step=".0001" min="0" placeholder="0.0000"/>
        <input id="delete_VolumeRate" type="button" name="delete_VolumeRate" value="Delete" onclick="removeItem('volumeRateDivNew_1')"/>
</div>
</div>

var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("volumeRateDivChild");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    var div = divs[i];
    alert (div.className+" - "+div.id+" - "+div.children[0].value );
}
```

Comment: Sadly it is not from the first child of the parent 'volumeRateDiv', these children are dynamically added/removed, then clicking on a submit button needs to have the javascript read through what is left and proceed with DB updates/adds etc.

Comment: The script above takes the first child element (which in this case is the input with id "kc_start") of the "volumeRateDivChild" not "volumeRateDiv"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @tymeJV already had mentioned, ids of HTML elements must be unique. So you need remove them or make them unique, if you plan to use them anywhere else (not in this case).

To locate elements inside your divs you could use classes or names. You can call `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByName` not only on `document`, but on any DOM-element. It could look like this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("volumeRateDivChild");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    var div = divs[i];
    alert(div.className+" - "+div.id+" - "+div.getElementsByName("kc_start")[0].value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("volumeRateDivChild");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    var div = divs[i];
    alert (div.className+" - "+div.id+" - "+div.children["kc_start"].value );
}
```

**Demo:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sb5oyaeu/)